# setting a timer for promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am trying to set a timer within my promises. They all seem to return instantly and the timer I attempt to create does not actually increase the time between returns 
all the functions return at once, I need them to be spaced apart in time say for example: function 1 (wait 4 seconds) function 2 (wait 4 seconds) etc..

I have tried using

```
.then(()=>{
    let counter=0
    while(counter < 6000){
      counter+=1
    }
     this.props.toggleMenu()
  })
```

here is my current example it calls multiple functions that need to execute one at a time in my application

```
rundemo=()=>{
  //function is designed to run all the essential functions in the app one after another

  const wait = time => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));

  var docvalue= document.getElementById('regex-example').value
  var selection = this.range(0,20,docvalue)//get selected chars in element
  var selectedText = selection.toString(); //sends the elements to a string


  wait(6000).then(() =>   this.props.setHighlightMode() )
  .then(()=>{
    let counter=0
    while(counter < 6000){
      counter+=1
    }
     this.props.toggleMenu()
  })
  .then(()=>{
    let counter=0
    while(counter < 6000){
      counter+=1
    }
    this.props.openNotes()
  })
  .then(()=>{
    let counter=0
    while(counter < 6000){
      counter+=1
    }
    this.props.close()
  })
  .then(()=>{
    let counter=0
    while(counter < 6000){
      counter+=1
    }
    this.props.setScholarMode()
  })
  .then(()=>{
    let counter=0
    while(counter < 6000){
      counter+=1
    }
    this.props.DemosynonymsFunction("noun")
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a `wait` function, instead of waiting using `while`, you could chin those promises :

```
rundemo = () => {
  //function is designed to run all the essential functions in the app one after another

  const wait = time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));

  var docvalue = document.getElementById("regex-example").value;
  var selection = this.range(0, 20, docvalue); //get selected chars in element
  var selectedText = selection.toString(); //sends the elements to a string

  wait(6000)
    .then(() => this.props.setHighlightMode())
    .then(wait(6000))
    .then(() => this.props.toggleMenu())
    .then(wait(6000))
    .then(() => this.props.openNotes())
    .then(wait(6000))
    .then(() => this.props.close())
    .then(wait(6000))
    .then(() => this.props.setScholarMode())
    .then(wait(6000))
    .then(() => this.props.DemosynonymsFunction("noun"));
};
```

If those functions don't return promisese, chain them like :

```
wait(6000)
    .then(() => this.props.setHighlightMode())
    .then(() => wait(6000).then(() => this.props.toggleMenu()))
    .then(() => wait(6000).then(() => this.props.openNotes()))
    .then(() => wait(6000).then(() => this.props.close()))
    .then(() => wait(6000).then(() => this.props.setScholarMode()))
    .then(() => wait(6000).then(() => this.props.DemosynonymsFunction("noun")));
```

Comment: Hi thank you the second option worked perfectly! though I don't understand why the first option did not? Could you elaborate on how your two solutions differ? I'm new to promises.

Comment: the first one didn't work probably because you functions don't return promises like `wiat`, check this for more details on [promises chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to return a promise that resolves after a certain period of time. Return that inside your `then` so that the succeeding `then` in the chain waits for it. In your case, you already have your `wait` function:

```
wait(6000)
  .then(() => { this.props.setHighlightMode() })
  .then(() => wait(6000).then(() => { this.props.toggleMenu() }))
  .then(() => wait(6000).then(() => { this.props.openNotes() }))
  .then(() => wait(6000).then(() => { this.props.close() }))
  .then(() => wait(6000).then(() => { this.props.setScholarMode() }))
  .then(() => wait(6000).then(() => { this.props.DemosynonymsFunction("noun") }))
```

Or when written inside an async function:

```
await wait(6000)
this.props.setHighlightMode()

await wait(6000)
this.props.toggleMenu()

await wait(6000)
this.props.openNotes()

await wait(6000)
this.props.close()

await wait(6000)
this.props.setScholarMode()

await wait(6000)
this.props.DemosynonymsFunction("noun")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion for that, here is an example:

```
const functions = [this.props.toggleMenu, this.props.openNotes, this.prop.close, .....];
function process(arr, index) {
  if (index < arr.length) {
    arr[index]();
    setTimeout(process.bind(this, arr, ++index), 6000);
  }
}
process(functions, 0);
```

This will run the function with a 6 seconds delay between the, if you want different pauses for different function, you can add the timeout's time as a parameter to the `process` function or set it based on the next function in the array.

Or, if you want to use promises, you can do something like this:

```
const pause = (time) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));

const functions = [this.props.toggleMenu, this.props.openNotes, this.prop.close, .....];

functions.reduce(
  (p, fn) => p.then(fn).then(pause(6000)),
  Promise.resolve()
).then(() => {
  // All done.
});
```